# LinearLayout (vertical) putt 2 Buttons side by side and more buttons below

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some little problems at creating some buttons. I want to Place 2 Buttons side by side (worked) and more (exp. 3 Buttons) below in a LinearLayout. Actually everything is working for me but if I put another Button the button is below but above there is free space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" >


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thats how it looks like atm.

[image]

Comment: the problem is with your marginBottom

Answer (score 1):

first make the width of each button 0dp. 
second make the margin bottom equal in the 3 buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" >


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1, if using `layout_weight` the proper approach is to set the width to 0dp. But `layout_weight` doesn't mean much without a `weightSum` in the parent layout ;)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/layout_one">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button 1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button 2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_one"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button 3"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the screenshot of pic:

[image: screenshot of pic]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" >


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Update your xml with this one, Hope it helps you

Comment: Hello, I also know this method changing it to horizontal, but with horizonal I am not able to put a button below the first button

Comment: what u need to do? I dont understand

Comment: you need three button side by side right? and what else you need?

Answer (score 0):

here is your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:text="Button2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:text="Button3"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Just make `android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />` in 2nd button.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because You have gave the centre gravity to `LinearLayout`.

The solution is only that you just remove that `gravity` tag and run again

**Replace this**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
```

**to this**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place the 3 buttons below each other, you should set the orientation of your LinearLayout to vertical instead of horizontal. This will display your buttons in a vertical order.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:text="Button2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:text="Button3"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```